# Sanskrit on overleaf.com

Tags: xetex, hindi

Trying to compile this on overleaf. Producing error. Can someone help ?

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{sanskrit} %% or other languages
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Devanagari}
%\usecolortheme{beetle}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usepackage{palatino, amssymb, wasysym, animate, multicol}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\title{Demo}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame} {basti}
\begin{exampleblock}
\begin{sanskrit}
वस्तिना दीयते इति वस्तिः।(अ.हृ.सू.१९/१, अरुणदत्त)
बस्तिभिः दीयते यस्मात् तस्मात् वस्तिः इति स्मृतः।(शा.उ.ख.५/१)
\end{Sanskrit}
\begin{exampleblock}
\begin{itemize} 
\item Mother of all Panchakarma therapies 
\item Cleanses all the accumulated toxins from all 3 doshas (Vaat, Pitta, and Kapha) through the colon 
\item Highly beneficial rejuvinating therapy 
\end {itemize} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You have `\begin{sanskrit}` and `\end{Sanskrit}`. Use `\end{sanskrit}`, as (La)TeX is case-sensitive.

Comment: Error: Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Devanagari script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \devanagarifont with \newfontfamily.


See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.68 \end{frame}

Comment: @Vaibhav You sure that's the *first* error?

Comment: @egreg Yes! Rechecked.

Comment: Remove `palatino`, to begin with, and add `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`.

Comment: @egreg Does not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main error is due to the fact that the standard font family used by `beamer` is sans serif, so you need to define `\devanagarifontsf` (the error message is indeed pretty uninformative, a know issue).

Remove `palatino` that only makes things more difficult.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
%\usecolortheme{beetle}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usepackage{amssymb, wasysym, animate, multicol}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{sanskrit} %% or other languages
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{ITF Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{ITF Devanagari}

\title{Demo}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{basti}
\begin{exampleblock}{}
\begin{sanskrit}
वस्तिना दीयते इति वस्तिः।(अ.हृ.सू.१९/१, अरुणदत्त)
बस्तिभिः दीयते यस्मात् तस्मात् वस्तिः इति स्मृतः।(शा.उ.ख.५/१)
\end{sanskrit}
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{itemize} 
\item Mother of all Panchakarma therapies 
\item Cleanses all the accumulated toxins from all 3 doshas (Vaat, Pitta, and Kapha) through the colon 
\item Highly beneficial rejuvinating therapy 
\end {itemize} 
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

I used a Devanagari font I have on my machine.

Some other points:

1. you had `\end{Sanskrit}`, but it should be `\end{sanskrit}`
2. you had `\begin{exampleblock}` where `\end{exampleblock}` was needed
3. you missed the mandatory argument after `\begin{exampleblock}`

[image]